# Calling API Json Path FlutterFlow

Tags: json, api, flutterflow

I have a built a list in my app and I can call my API. However, when I paste my $..title.rendered path in the variable in each card it shows me all the titles rather than having in each card 1 title and second title in second card so on...

[image: Picture of code]

Try to render it in various paths still same issue

Comment: Please include the code and results  in the question as text, not as pictures. Using pictures makes it difficult for some people to read what you wrote, it stops them copying an pasting to try and reproduce your problem. It also makes it more difficult for someone with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the API should be added outside the column.